# Localization Information (Globalization)

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

As at 2013 what is the best practice for multi language multi culture localization of web pages.

Should I store all the translations in a database? for language etc?

Should I build resx files based on a database query or should I simply create resx files?

The application will be used with a browser interface across multiple devices and platforms e.g. Windows/IOS/Android.  Are there any additional things I should think about.

best regards

Shrekito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few types of global content you will usually have to deal with:

- Application templates such as HTML pages, menus, and emails sent by your app
- Dynamic content stored in your database

**App templates**

Templates are typically handled using your own framework's internationalization (i18n) framework. In the case of asp.net, the framework includes libraries to mark strings and export them to (English) .resx files. This supports a lot of built-in features such as variables, plurals, and developer comments. So unless you're facing some actual blockers, you typically want to go with it instead of building your own i18n framework (eg. in-database, or in-DB with .resx export).

Nowadays, the workflow decisions come when you actually want to get those files *localized*. In the old days you'd exchange the files with an agency using email. In 2013, web apps have a fast-paced development cycle with multiple releases per week (or per day), so there is a much bigger need for automation. Teams are switching away from using a VCS, FTP or Dropbox as a temporary storage for their files to modern localization (L10n) management platforms like [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com) (discl: I'm the founder) to manage their localization process.

The best way to remove the L10n pain from developers is to integrate your L10n platform with your build tools, so whenever you commit something, the English files are sent automatically to the L10n system, which will detect the changes and notify the right translators. When you're ready to deploy, your integration will pull the fresh translated files automatically.

With Transifex, you can use the Tx Client app with a git-commit hook, your build/CI system or your ol' good deploy script:

`tx push --source`

`tx pull -l de,fr,it  --mode=reviewed --minimum-perc=90`

**Dynamic and External content**

This type of content is typically not handled using .resx files since it's easier to manage it in your DB itself. Typically, you want to store this content along with your template content so that translators have a single place to look at everything.

The platform you choose will need to have a modern API to work with. Check out the [Transifex API](http://support.transifex.com/customer/portal/topics/440186-api/articles) on how these look like.

**Other tips and tricks**

- Choose a platform which has a strong built-in web-based translation editor. Translators need solid features such as Translation Memory, Glossary, Machine Translation to deliver quality and consistent translations.
- Follow good i18n practices such as good date formatting and avoiding concatenation.
- Love your translators. They're the ones who make it all happen.

Comment: Hi glezos,  Thanks for taking the time to complete a comprehensive reply and excuse my tardiness in saying thank you - I read the reply and then lost my email access - long story and I've only recently got back on the grid. The developers in this case went with the resx file / translation route. best regards Shrekito

Comment: PS I couldn't vote your answer up as I don't have sufficient reputation yet.